# Is it possible to upload video (size > 20GB) at a time by using php as technology?

Tags: php, youtube

Is it possible to upload the VIDEO having size greater than 100 GB using php ?

E.g. a user can upload the video having size <= 128GB in youtube.

Comment: am not sure about it, but i think we can do it if we change the value of `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini` file...

Comment: In php max_upload_size is equals to 64 M only

Comment: Use a library like uploadify that breaks the file into smaller chunks to upload it, then puts them all back together again afterwards

Comment: You can change it to your own value know..

Comment: For a file this size, you'll want restart capability. Write an uploader program and use something like `rsync` internally.

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining the following constants in your script

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

The 10M is 10 megabytes. Simply increase this (And the input/execution time which is in seconds). Play about with it and see where it takes you.

You probably don't want to write a script allowing people to upload 100GB files however. Not unless you're Youtube and can re-encode them to compress them on the backend.

And next time, actually do your own research and try something before posting a question. Google is covered with answers to this, [as is Stack overflow](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F16102809%2Fhow-to-upload-large-files-above-500mb-in-php&ei=FaD1VJ2QIcSzUffQgOgG&usg=AFQjCNHDP35n0K24e4Xq80Rvt8ttWWKWyg&sig2=2fh5APFja41wBafRsOYMlw).

Answer (score -1):

At first you can not write a PHP script that will be used at different web sites, since PHP is server based. Besides of that Youtube has it's own defined video size limitation.

If you want to do that in your own website, there should be a solution for that I think. Sure, the regular simple Upload probably couldn't handle that, but since the PHP community is huge, there should be some library or source code for free for uploading huge file amounts.
For this just search the web.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do that by swfuploader because by that you can see the progress of the file otherwise it will be load and load and you will think that the system is hanged.

Also you have to set the max file size of the PHP to Unlimited either by php.ini or by using php function.